# In "Solo," how did Enfys Nest keep catching up to Beckett?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

There were two times that Enfys Nest and the Cloud-Riders seemed to appear at just the right time and place to thwart Tobias Beckett. The first is when Beckett and crew were doing the job with the Conveyex, and the second is when Nest's crew places a tracker on the Millennium Falcon. (Their encounter on Savareen is understandable given the tracker, which may be one of the only thing that didn't fall off the Falcon during its trip through the Maelstrom!)

In both cases, how did Nest know where to find Beckett? The story didn't seem to indicate whether they were tipped off, or whether they had a spy. They just... knew where to be?

Comment: Hope to see next "Solo" part, with some answers too =)

Comment: I agree! Solo II would be such a great movie. It would at least include Jabba and Boba Fett, and maybe more of Lando!

Comment: My understanding from the movie was that the first time they had also been after that shipment, rather than attempting to thwart Beckett specifically. And my understanding of the second was that planet was more of where they lived, and Beckett and the others stumbled upon it. I might be misremembering though. it has been a while since i watched it.

Comment: @shufly, that’s what i remeber as well. The icy planet was just the fact they were going for the same target, while the deserty planet was their HQ